# Why is p(x) hard to calculate in a VAE?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, variational-bayes

In VAEs, it is hard to calculate the posterior: $p_\theta(z|x)$ because that reduces to:

$$
\frac{p(x|z)p(z)}{p(x)}
$$

which is difficult to calculate because $p(x)$ is hard to calculate.
But why exactly is $p(x)$ hard to calculate?
Is it because you must do the following to calculate it:

- For each image, loop over every possible latent encoding and calculate the probability the latent encoding results in the given image.
- Thus, you must do (number of images) * (number of latent encoding) loop iterations, which is too many?

Specifically, the thing I'm confused about is. Given that the likelihood and the posterior are kind of inverses of each other, why would one be much harder to calculate than the other?

Comment: In general $p(x)=\sum\limits_z p(x \mid z)p(z)$ or its integral equivalent.  That can be a substantial calculation, possibly intractable,  if there are large number of possibilities for $z$

Comment: @Henry, would it be possible for you to give a concrete example with some dataset. (for example: images of handwritten digits).

Comment: If $z$ has only ten possibilities, then the sum is not particularly difficult, and the hard part is the $p(x \mid z)$ calculation.

Comment: You've asked for a concrete example with a dataset, but this is about the design of the model—which can be whatever you want it to be.